# Track memory usage over a long period of time

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, memory

I own a 2019 Macbook Pro with 16GB of RAM for software development.

Previously I used a MBP with 32GB of RAM, and now I feel that sometimes the 16GB MBP hits the ceiling when running multiple things at once.

What I need is a graphic to show me the RAM usage (percentage preferably) over the past month, not only since I opened the laptop. I don't see how can I see that with Activity Monitor and I did not find anything else.

I am open for paid software as well. Are there tools for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) includes a graph of memory use which can go back 30 days. It is also available on the Mac App Store

Comment: Do you know of any free options?